# Bible unique word counter bottleneck

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

We are suppose to make a program which counts all of the unique words found in a text file of the King James Bible and prints out the most frequently used words. My function to count the number of unique words is taking way too slow:

```
public int parseBook(File fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

    scan = new Scanner(fileName);
    String currentWord = scan.next();
    Word firstWord = new Word(currentWord);
    allWords.add(firstWord);
    wordCount++;
    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        currentWord = scan.next();
            Word newWord = new Word(currentWord);
            if(!allWords.contains(newWord)) {
                uniquewordList.add(newWord);


            }

            else {
                newWord.incrementFrequency();
            }
            allWords.add(newWord);

    }
    return uniquewordList.size();
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? It's slow or the file isn't found? Please take the [tour] and read [ask] a good question. Then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: it dosent output anything but i don`t get a file not found exception, so im guessing its slow

Comment: You know the Bible text is quite long, right? :) How fast are you expecting this to return results? But nowhere in the code you posted do you try to output/print anything. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue...

Comment: some of my friends said it took them around 10 seconds

Comment: Well, you haven't posted enough code for us to see what it's doing. Maybe run your code with a debugger and find out what's taking so long? Or read the links I posted...

Comment: It would be simpler to add all words to a  [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which does not allow duplicate entries.

Comment: we arent allowed to do that we havent learned about sets yet

Comment: by the way i tried using a debugger and my computer started to really heat up

Comment: It's been a long time since I did any real performance optimization, but what data structures are you allowed to use ?  That's an important part of this question.

Comment: this is an intro course so the bare basics nothing fancy

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand the question. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help. It would also help if you collect all the information from your comments in the question itself (use the edit link) so we have everything in one place. Finally, how big is your file approximately?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. Just use `Set` and put all word in it. It takes **O(1)** to insert a word into `Set`.

```
public static int getUniqueWordsAmount(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            words.add(scan.next().trim().toLowerCase());

        return words.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: No chance! To make appropriate speed, it should be used `Set` or `Map`.